# Remove table spacing but keep borders

Tags: html, css

I have a table in which I want each of its td elements to have no space between each other. However, I still want borders between each td(so you can actually tell them apart). Unfortunately, when I try either or both of the following:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

My borders disappear entirely. I tried giving the td elements outlines through css, but that didn't work either. I looked at several different threads about html table spacing, but none of them talk about retaining borders after removing the space.

The reason I need this feature is because I want a fluid hover effect between each td, and having that small gap ruins the effect.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Just remove all padding from within the table elements, that should fix your issue. It would leave the borders on the table but remove all of the spacing

Comment: I love how someone -1'd me lol. It's an easy fix to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table><tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr><tr><td>e</td><td>f</td><td>g</td><td>h</td></tr><tr><td>i</td><td>j</td><td>k</td><td>l</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: I've tried this before and it didn't work. No matter what size of border I made the td, it never showed up.

Comment: If you click on `run code snippet`, is that the effect you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I removed all my margins and padding like mentioned above and that did the trick. I have the same styling as you, but I guess I had some weird hidden margins/padding that were screwing it up.

Comment: Please have a read of this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example